# Is an Hidden Service directory the same thing as a Directory Server?

Tags: onion-services, directory

I'm trying to get a better idea of the cast of characters that comprise the Tor network structure and am hung up a bit on the distinction between these.

Comment: As far as i am concerned,in this place Directory Server may has the same meaning as authority directory.and hidden service directory is just a relay(router) which has the hsdir flag